# How to pass an optional date or date range to a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Does anyone have an easy way to create a SQL Server stored procedure that accepts optional dates, either no date, just one date or two dates (a date range)?

I can do it with one date, like this:

```
WHERE (@PeriodFrom IS NULL OR Period = @PeriodFrom)
```

That works with a specified date or no date at all (I use

```
DECLARE @PeriodFor DATE = NULL
```

at the top of the stored procedure.

What if I want the query to go

```
WHERE
    Period BETWEEN @PeriodFrom AND @PeriodTo
```

Should I write some kind of `CASE` statement? Seems like it would get messy. Any suggestions?

Comment: Without dynamic SQL, you’ll need to manually define every possible combination of prefucate clauses. That’s just how SQL is…

Comment: Yes, it gets messy when you are letting users choose 15 different ways to filter. But [dynamic SQL is definitely more optimizer-friendly](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example) than a whole bunch of ORs, and is not really any more complex aside from sea-of-red readability.

Comment: Dai, what is a "prefucate clause"?

Comment: Yeah Aaron, I get the concept and so on, and I looked at the web site you linked, but I keep getting a syntax error here and there when I write my own version of that dynamic SQL, usually something like "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near ')'."  and I can't figure out where it's gone wrong...the parentheses look OK to me....argh!

Comment: With 0-2 dates it should be fairly trivial to use a combination or AND/OR logic.

Comment: We can't guess where you got your syntax wrong. Put something on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk) and we can take a look, otherwise I'm not sure how we can help.

Comment: @BrianBattles Typo. I meant **predicate clause**. Unfortunately SO only lets you edit comments for up to 5 minutes.

Comment: Hi Dai, thanks for clarifying that, I was wondering if there was some new concept in SQL Server that I had never heard of! (If they ever add a "prefucate clause" you should claim the copyright!)

Answer (score 0):

Without sample data and desired output I am guessing you want something like this.

```
WHERE
(
    Period > @PeriodFrom 
    OR
    @PeriodFrom IS NULL
)
AND
(
    Period < @PeriodTo
    OR
    @PeriodTo IS NULL
)
```

Comment: Yeah I'm trying something like that in my WHERE clause:

AND
(@PeriodFrom IS NULL OR Period >= @PeriodFrom)
AND
(@PeriodTo IS NULL OR Period <= @PeriodTo)

Comment: @BrianBattles and that isn't working?

Comment: Yes it is, but it's pretty slow...better than nothing, I guess

Comment: @BrianBattles performance is an entirely different question... this is the logic required. Now look at your indexes... for example do you have an index on Period?

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with it, and I haven't made my mind up yet. So far I haven't seen an answer that I'm satisfied is the best solution.

Comment: So what about this doesn't meet your needs? You said it might be a bit slow but there are a number of reasons that could be the case. But whatever. You got an answer.